# Менди - она или он?

Tags: род

Какого рода слово "менди" (в значении ритуального индийского рисунка, временной татуировки), и как правильно его употребить в контексте - "телесная менди"/ "телесный менди"?

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, женского. Словари молчат, но женский род мотивирован родовым словом (роспись, татуировка).

Что касается ссылки на Вики, приведенной Завадой, то чуть ниже в той же статье есть и пример употребления в женском роде: "В Европу менди пришла довольно недавно".

Answer (score 1):

Среднего. Tелесное менди.

Менди появилось около 5000 лет назад.

ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Менди

Answer (score 0):

Женский род: татуировка - она. Как салями, колибри.

Answer (score 0):

Так как слово не русское, то к нему сложно подобрать тот или иной род в русском языке, вне зависимости от данных словарей. Слово следует склонять от прилагающего к нему существительного. Рисунок мехенди - муж. род; роспись мехенди - жен. род; изображение мехенди - ср.род. и т.д.

Comment: Пусть будет мехенди, хотя вопрос про "менди". Но — Какого рода слово?

Answer (score 0):

В википедии даётся информация, что это "оно", но в исходном языке (наследующем санскриту) слово оканчивается на долгую и, а значит, относится к женскому роду. В приводимой статье менди трижды упоминается в среднем роде, и единожды - в женском: "[В Европу менди пришл ***а*** сравнительно недавно](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8)"...

Родовые соответствия при заимствовании из санскрита и(ли) наследующих ему языков в русский опциональны для слов тройственного (мужской-средний-женский) или двойственного (мужской-женский, как в испанском) исходных грамматических родов, а также для неодушевленных / небиотических существительных (включая имевшие в санскрите женский род):

Средний род:

[бодхи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%85%D0%B8), [бхакти](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8), брахми, деванагари, [гурмукхи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%85%D0%B8), [гхи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%85%D0%B8), [бинди](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8), сари.

Названия языков, наследующих и(ли) наследующие санскриту, получают мужской род: хинди, маратхи, пали, гуджарати, пахари, невари, майтхили, магахи, панджаби.

(Слово "пехлеви" относится к среднему роду, поскольку заимствовано из иранского, а не из наследующего санскриту языка).

В целом же преобладает тенденция сохранения исходного грамматического рода. Так, к женскому роду относятся следующие заимствования: [джати](http://www.pravenc.ru/text/171819.html), [пракрити](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8), [туласи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8), нагини, ракшаси, якши (якшини), дэви, [нади](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8) (отмечено одно рематическое употребление в мужском роде при видовом пояснительном слове "канал"), шакти, йони...

...и множество других.

Таким образом, для неодушевленных существительных, заимствованных из санскрита и наследующих ему языков, в русском преобладают две стратегии:

а) сохранение исходного грамматического рода (для одушевленных и(ли) "биотических" существительных), либо

б) определение грамматического рода по принадлежности к родовому слову (так, все названия языков получают мужской род, поскольку они охватываются определением "язык", имеющим в русском мужской род; слово "гхи" - средний, как "масло", а слова "деванагари", "брахми", "гурмукхи" - средний, поскольку родовое определение, "письмо", в русском - среднего рода).